# How do you format a micro sd card?

Tags: format, sd-card

I recently bought this micro sd card, and I think I am having trouble formating it. In my mp3 player, it says card error. So I took it to the computer. After clicking on the file icon, I clicked on the memory card. [image: memory card 1] Then, after clicking on it get this error message. [image: memory card 2]  Can anyone help me with this problem? Thank you all in your efforts.

I installed gparted but I am still having trouble. I got rid of the exclamation point though, and I think I found a clue. I got a new error message after clicking on the file system. [image: memory card 3]

Comment: reboot again and try

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use ***Disks*** (a.k.a. `gnome-disks`).

If you cannot find it in your menu, you need to go to a terminal by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> and type:

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-disk-utility
```

This is a tool to manage disk drives and media:

- Format and partition drives.
- Mount and unmount partitions.
- Query S.M.A.R.T. attributes. It utilizes udisks.

---

It provides two options:

1. Formatting the entire disk:

[image: Format Disk Menu]

and

2. Formatting each separate partition

[image: Format Partition Menu]

Answer (score 1):

You should install the following packages to support exfat in Ubuntu (14.04 or higher):

```
sudo apt-get install exfat-fuse exfat-utils
```

Answer (score 1):

I think there is something built-in with 16.04. Just type " Disk " on dash and you will get something called " Disks ". It should show you all mounted volumes in your PC. And, as far as I can remember, it allows you to format the volume as well (on right clicking the drive ).